# jquery request running more than once

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, request

I have this code to make a request to a file that process some xls files ( with phpexcel library ) :

```
$("#applyCalls").click(function(){
    $.get("admin/processCalls.php");
});
```

the processCalls.php looks like this:

```
include '../phpexcel2/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
include '../phpexcel2/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Bucharest');

$fisierInbound = "inbound.xls";
$fisierOutbound = "outbound.xls";

callsInbound();

function callsInbound() {

        global $fisierInbound;
        global $current;

        global $con;

        $identify = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify('daily/' . $fisierInbound);
        $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($identify);
        $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
        $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load('daily/' . $fisierInbound);
        $worksheet = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

        $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE tip_user='agent' AND NOT (departament='online')");

        while($usr = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                        $data[] = $usr;
        }

        $worksheetTitle     = $worksheet->getTitle();
        $highestRow         = $worksheet->getHighestRow(); // e.g. 10
        $highestColumn      = $worksheet->getHighestColumn(); // e.g 'F'
        $highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);
        $dataCalls = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2, 2)->getValue();
        $dataSubstr = substr($dataCalls, 53);
        echo $dataSubstr;
        foreach ($data as $db) {

            for ($row = 6; $row <= $highestRow; ++ $row) {

                $marca      = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(3, $row)->getValue();
                $nr         = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(4, $row)->getValue();

                if($db['marca'] == $marca) {
                    mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO dailycalls(data, nr, departament, oras, tip, id_user)
                                        VALUES('$dataSubstr', '$nr', '" . $db['departament'] . "', '" . $db['oras'] . "', 'inbound', '" . $db['id'] . "')");
                }
            }
        }
}
```

The thing is that I get "No data receive Error code: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE" (chrome) from processCalls, so the ajax  request fails. As it fails I think it is running the file more than once, because I get more results than I need in the db. If I run the file manually I get the results I need. ( side note: the processCalls.php's query runs despite the error I get ). I hope that makes sense.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check if the click function is getting binded more than once.

If the click function is binded more than once the function will be called multiple times.

```
$("#applyCalls").off('click', callServer).on('click', callServer);

var callServer = function(){
    $.get("admin/processCalls.php");
};
```

Comment: In the console I see a single request, wich it fails after 3 - 4 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `stopPropagation()` function.

Also as your PHP doesn't return anything you should use `POST` instead of `GET`

To understand the difference between `POST` and `GET` have a look at [this article](http://www.jquery4u.com/ajax/key-differences-post/)

```
$("#applyCalls").click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation()
    $.post("admin/processCalls.php");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
$("#applyCalls").unbind("click").click(function(){$.get("admin/processCalls.php");});
```

Comment: .off .on seems to be the way to do this now